# Container for a limited group of classes

Tags: c++, variables, pointers

**EDIT:**

Thanks everybody that spend a time for my question. I completely agree that my question wasn't clearly.

**In short:** My question was how can I make a limited pointer container, that can hold only class from limited group of classes. I called it *enum*, and this was a big mistake. As I wrote, the polymorphism isn't the main issue, it was only an illustration.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: Couldn't able to understand what you are trying to do...

Comment: Out of interest people does `class DOG::animal` mean the same thing as `class DOG : public animal`?  Also why are `dog::jump` and `cat::jump` declared with fully qualified names, is that necessary?

Comment: Voted to reopen, the edit clarified the question and it is now answerable. :) Hint since I can't post an answer until it's open again: [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/variant.html), which is kind of a union.

Comment: I don't know what the norm is on here but wouldn't it be better to leave the original question in place and open a new one for the re-posed question?  It's a bit annoying to write an answer that becomes useless due to such shenanigans ;-)

Comment: (though on the plus side I got to learn about boost::variant yay)

Comment: @Sideshow Bob I ask the same question twice. My problem was that in the first time it wasn't clearly.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** this answers the poster's original question, not the current one.  enjoy.

It looks like what you're trying to do might be this.

```
class Animal
{
    virtual void jump() = 0;
};

class Dog : public Animal
{
    virtual void jump() { do stuff here; }
    void bark() { other stuff; } // method peculiar to dogs
};

class Cat : public Animal
{
    virtual void jump() { do stuff here; }
};

void main()
{
    Animal *a = new Dog(); // abstract types have to be referred to by pointers
    a->jump();
    delete a;

    Dog d;
    d.bark(); // if the compiler knows it's a dog, it can do dog things
    Animal *b = &d;
    b->jump(); // although b came from d, it's an animal so can only jump not bark
}
```

Now do you really need to know whether an `Animal` is a `Dog` or a `Cat` at runtime?  This would break encapsulation - presumably you are subclassing Animal because you want to *hide* the Animal type, not *reveal* it.

If so you can use `dynamic_cast` and/or run-time type identification http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeid which will tell you whether each class is a cat or dog.

Comment: No need for `animal_type`, that's what `dynamic_cast` is for.

Answer (score 2):

Like I already said in my comment, you can do this with [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/variant.html). There's also the other way, and the more natural, and that is the usual class hierarchy with polymorphism.

Since there are already answers on the hierarchy version, I'm going to focus on the variant version here.

First the code, an explanation afterwards:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

struct Cat{
  void speak() const{ std::cout << "meow\n"; }
  void cat_extra() const{ std::cout << "Special cat move!\n"; }
  ~Cat(){ std::cout << "Cat died\n"; }
};

struct Dog{
  void speak() const{ std::cout << "wuff\n"; }
  void dog_extra() const{ std::cout << "Special dog move!\n"; }
  ~Dog(){ std::cout << "Dog died\n"; }
};

struct Bird{
  void speak() const{ std::cout << "chirp\n"; }
  void bird_extra() const{ std::cout << "Special bird move!\n"; }
  ~Bird(){ std::cout << "Bird died\n"; }
};

struct Fish{
  void speak() const{ std::cout << "blub\n"; }
  void fish_extra() const{ std::cout << "Special fish move!\n"; }
  ~Fish(){ std::cout << "Fish died\n"; }
};

struct speak_visitor
    : boost::static_visitor<void>
{
    template<class Animal>
    void operator()(Animal const* p) const{
        p->speak();
    }
};

struct extra_visitor
    : boost::static_visitor<void>
{
    void operator()(Cat const* p) const{
        p->cat_extra();
    }
    void operator()(Dog const* p) const{
        p->dog_extra();
    }
    void operator()(Bird const* p) const{
        p->bird_extra();
    }
    void operator()(Fish const* p) const{
        p->fish_extra();
    }
};

struct delete_visitor
    : boost::static_visitor<void>
{
    template<class Animal>
    void operator()(Animal const* p) const{
        delete p;
    }
};

int main(){
    typedef boost::variant<Cat*, Dog*, Bird*, Fish*> variant_type;
    variant_type var;
    speak_visitor sv;
    delete_visitor dv;
    extra_visitor ev;

    var = new Cat();
    var.apply_visitor(sv);
    var.apply_visitor(ev);
    var.apply_visitor(dv);

    var = new Dog();
    var.apply_visitor(sv);
    var.apply_visitor(ev);
    var.apply_visitor(dv);

    var = new Bird();
    var.apply_visitor(sv);
    var.apply_visitor(ev);
    var.apply_visitor(dv);

    var = new Fish();
    var.apply_visitor(sv);
    var.apply_visitor(ev);
    var.apply_visitor(dv);
}
```

[Running example on Ideone](http://ideone.com/X8zoz).

Now on to the explanation. A `boost::variant` is basically an enhanced and tagged `union`. A `union` can store different stuff, but only one at a time. Same goes for a variant. A `boost::variant` is tagged, because you can find out which type is currently stored with the `which` member function, which will return a 0-based index depending on which type is currently stored. The linked documentation will explain a variant better than I possibly can.

For safe "visitation" of the stored value, a construct named "visitor" is required. The visitor concept is a great one, and there are many resources out there which describe it. The linked documentation goes into some details too here. Basically, the variant internally does a `switch` on the stored type (with `which`) and calls the variant's `operator()` with the appropriate argument, something like this:

```
// something similar to this happens internally in `apply_visitor`
// contrived for our example classes here
template<class V>
void variant::apply_visitor(V& v){
  switch(this->which()){
    case 0: v((Cat*)&(this->internal_storage)); break;
    case 1: v((Dog*)&(this->internal_storage)); break;
    case 2: v((Bird*)&(this->internal_storage)); break;
    case 3: v((Fish*)&(this->internal_storage)); break;
  }
}
```

Thanks to this, the appropriate `operator()` with the appropriate argument is called. This also allows the compiler to catch a possible error when one of the variant types isn't handled by the supplied visitor, because no fitting overload for `operator()` is available.

This concept may not be entirely clear when using the generic visitors (`speak_visitor`, `delete_visitor`), but is made clear by the `extra_visitor`. If you comment out one of the `operator()` overloads in there, the compiler will barf at you.

If you have any questions, please let me know in the comments. And last but not least, I can only repeat that you should read the documentation. :)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want an enum? Why not do this?

```
class animal {public: virtual void jump() = 0;}; 
class DOG:public animal{public: virtual void dog::jump(){}}; 
class CAT:public animal{public: virtual void cat::jump(){}}; 
DOG dog; CAT cat;
animal &a1 = dog; // Using a reference
a1.jump();
animal *a2 = &dog; // Using a pointer
a2->jump();
```

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the :: type of the question but oversaw the public/private issue. I now added "public" where necessary.

Comment: That fixed it. Using `struct` instead of `class` would have been sufficient though :)